# Sending and receiving data to and from the same page with Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I want to send data to a page(as radio buttons) and then record the input. Right now I am having a problem as I can't figure out how to do both using flask. 
Python:

```
...
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
   data = adb.fetch()
   return render_template('index.html', data=data)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_data():
    name = request.form['option']
    print name
```

and in HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#"
  class="form-horizontal" id="names" method ="post">
  <div class="control-group">
    {% for row in data %}
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio"
        name="option"
        id="{{row['lid']}}"
        value="{{row['name']}}"> {{row['name']}}
      </label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am getting proper output to the site, but result is not printed to my console.

How can I send and receive data on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

So this is a pretty basic property of flask but the answer is:

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', data=data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['option']
        print name
        return "Page submitted"
```